# Install a dependency "matching" the project dependencies

Tags: npm

I have an ionic application.
ionic `4.7.0` requires `rxjs@^5.0.1` so I installed an angular version to match that rxjs dependency, that is angular `5.2.10`.
Now I am trying to install `ngx-translate/core`.

Installing the latest version will require having `angular >= 6.0.0-rc0`.

Is there a way to specify to `npm` to install the latest `ngx-translate` version which needs angular to be no more than `5.2.10`? or is there a better way to handle this kind of problem with `npm`?